# Using python os.system to extract port from netstat and use it in variable

Tags: python-3.x, os.system, netstat

I am looking for a solution to extract port from netstat and use it as variable.
Issue is that when I print it, value is 0 although when I use same command in bash it returns correct port.

`device_port = os.system("netstat -atnp 2>/dev/null | awk '/adb/ {print $4}' | cut -d ':' -f 2")`

returns value 5037

`print(device_port)`

returns value 0

Im not sure why is this happening.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first command doesn't *return* 5037, it *prints* 5037. That's a difference.

Look at the documentation of `os.system`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system

It states that it will forward the stdout of the command to the console, and *return* the **exit code** of the command.

That's exactly what happens, your code prints 5037 to the console and returns 0 to indicate that the command succeeded.

---

### Fix:

Use `subprocess` instead of `os.system`. It's even recommended in the official documentation of `os.system`. That will allow you to capture the output and write it to a variable:

```py
import subprocess

command = subprocess.run("netstat -atnp 2>/dev/null | awk '/adb/ {print $4}' | cut -d ':' -f 2",
    check=True,  # Raise an error if the command failed
    capture_output=True,  # Capture the output (can be accessed via the .stdout member)
    text=True,  # Capture output as text, not as bytes
    shell=True)  # Run in shell. Required, because you use pipes.
    
device_port = int(command.stdout)  # Get the output and convert it to an int
print(device_port)  # Print the parsed port number
```

Here's a working example: https://ideone.com/guXXLl

I replaced your bash command with `id -u`, as your bash script didn't print anything on ideome, and therefore the `int()` conversion failed.

Comment: Thank you Finomnis! It works as you udescribed. Also thanks for recommendation regarding subprocess. I will switch all cmds from os.system to subprocess.